# How do I information about signal strength of wifi connected to my Android Phone?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an app that can tell you the signal strength of a wifi access point it's currently connected to. I'm using Android Studios and am a beginner.  How do I retrieve this information? Any methods would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onReceive(WifiManager wifiManager) {
                      int numberOfLevels=5;
                      WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                      int level=WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);
                      System.out.println("Bars =" +level);
                }
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I be able to convert that reading into a rough estimate for distance?

Comment: that's not possible.. since it depends on the wifi router strength.. 
just because strength is high you can't estimate distance as low

Comment: How would I go about initializing it? I'm sorry, I'm not too sure where to go from here. I want to be able to hit a button to have it tell me the strength.

Comment: What do you want to initialize? WifiManager?  Read more here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html .. For examples- http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.net.wifi.WifiManager -Replied from mobile